# restore from tar to specific location issues

Tags: tar

I have a `tar` file and when I list the files from `tar`, I can see them as follow:

```
-rw-rw-r-- root/ccs       3207 2017-02-15 18:43 HMS/PRE.UPG.APPROGS/AP.CLM.NEW
-rw-rw-r-- root/ccs        210 2017-02-15 18:43 HMS/PRE.UPG.APPROGS/AP.R.STUB_1
-rw-r--r-- ccs/ccs         128 2017-05-05 19:01 HMS/BP/_KI.TEST
-rw-rw-r-- ccs/ccs        2683 2017-05-05 19:01 HMS/BP/GET.TOKEN
and etc.
```

I would like all files and folders to be restored and overwrite (including sub-folders) `/usr/CCS/HMS`.

But when I ran the command below:

```
tar xvfz /usr/CCS/backup/hms1_24jan2018.tar.gz -C / HMS*
```

Instead of overwriting `/usr/CCS/HMS` and all sub-folders, the above command is restoring on the root as `/HMS`.

Can I please get some guidance, I would like the untar to overwrite all files and folders under `/usr/CCS/HMS` from the `tar` file.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using -C /usr/CSS ?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should be able to do

```
tar xvzf /usr/CCS/backup/hms1_24jan2018.tar.gz -C /usr/CCS
```

or, alternatively

```
cd /usr/CCS
tar xvzf /usr/CCS/backup/hms1_24jan2018.tar.gz
```

When you use `-C /`, the files will be unpacked into the root directory.  Since the path in the archive starts with `HMS/`, this will create a directory called `HMS` in the root of the filesystem hierarchy.

If you want to extract *all* files (as per your question), you should not specify filenames to extract (you have `HMS*` on the command line).

Note also that existing files under `/usr/CCS/HMS` that are not included in the archive will be left in place (unmodified). `tar` will not replace the full contents of a directory just because it happens to unpack a few files in it.

Comment: Thanks Kusalananda, let me run the tar xvzf /usr/CCS/backup/hms1_24jan2018.tar.gz -C /usr/CSS, will provide update soon.

Comment: I tried and got this error: [root@hms1 backup]# tar xvzf /usr/CCS/backup/hms1_24jan2018.tar.gz -C /usr/CSS
tar: /usr/CSS: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now. Please note that /usr/CCS folder exists, but the system in the command did not recognize /usr/CCS

Comment: @Muhammad I had written `CSS` in my answer rather than `CCS`. Sorry, now corrected.

Comment: Perfect, now running as advised, will provide update once finished.

Comment: Thank you Kusalananda, your solution worked perfectly. Thank you so much for everyone, help from this forum is amazing. God bless you all. We can mark this answered.

Comment: @Muhammad Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

It is creating folder in root and overriding it as you have used -C / HMS*.
Change it to -C /usr/CCS/HMS. It will override the required directory